# Reference for Fredholm Integral Equations..

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, integral-equations

Can anyone recommend me some nice books about [Fredholm integral equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation)? I'm looking for complete references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gripenberg, Londen, Staffans, Volterra Integral and Functional Equations (Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications)

Zemyan, The Classical Theory of Integral Equations, A Concise Treatment, Birkhauser

DiBenedetto, Partial differential equations, chap.4